# Vague error concerning TDBXerror

Tags: mysql, delphi

Please see the pic below.....

[image]

I am wondering about the cause of this error.

I am using Win7 Professional SP1, MySQL 5.6 Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7 abd dbExpress Driver

I am trying to connect to MySQL. Which client library could be?

Please help advise.

Clement

Comment: Is this on the machine where MySQL is installed?

Comment: Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit and which is your app?  Is libmysql.dll located where your Path environment variable can be used to find it?

Comment: Yes MyySQL is inside the PC I working with. It's 32-bit application running on 64-bit system type. FYI, the service's value for MySQL is MySQL56.